# App Server Clustering vs Terracotta

Tags: java, glassfish, cluster-computing, terracotta

I've heard the term "clustering" used for application servers like GlassFish, as well as with Terracotta; and I'm trying to understand what the word *clustering* implies when used in conjunction with application servers, and when used in conjunction with Terracotta.

My *understanding* is:

If a GlassFish server is clustered, then it means we have multiple physical/virtual machines, each with their own JRE/JVM running separate instances of GlassFish. However, since they are clustered, they will all communicate through their admin server ("DAS"), and have the same apps deployed to all of them. They will effectively act (to the end user) as if they are a single app server - but now with load balancing, failover/redundancy and scalability added into the mix.

Terracotta is, essentially, a product that makes multiple JVMs, running on different physical/virtual machines, act as if they are a single JVM.

Thus, if my understanding is correct, the following are implied:

- You cluster app servers when you want load balancing and failover tolerance
- You use Terracotta when any particular JVM is too small to contain your application and you need more "horsepower"
- Thus, technically, if you have a GlassFish cluster of, say, 5 server instances; each of those 5 instances could actually be an array/cluster of Terracotta instances; meaning each GlassFish server instance is actually a GlassFish instance living across the JVMs of  multiple machines itself

If any of these assertions/assumptions are untrue, please correct me! If I have gone way off-base and clearly don't understand clustering and/or the very purpose of Terracotta, please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terracotta enables you to have a shared state across all your nodes (its stateful). Basically it creates a shared memory space between different JVM's. This is useful when nodes in a cluster all need access to the same objects.

If your application is stateless and you just need load balancing and fail over you can use a solution like [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/). In this scenario each node just handles requests and has little idea about other nodes. Objects in memory are not shared across nodes and each JVM just runs on its own and has no idea about other JVM's. This often works nicely for request / response type applications. A webserver serving content (without sessions) does this for example.

Dealing with a stateless cluster is often simpler then dealing with a stateful cluster. This is because in a stateless cluster nodes know almost nothing about each other which results in less things that can go wrong.

GlassFish sits a bit in the middle of the above concepts. Objects in memory within GlassFish are visible to all nodes. However the frontend (HTTP connectors) work stateless.

So to answer your questions:

1) Yes, those are the two most obvious reasons. However sometimes people only want failover or only want load balancing or sometimes both. Not all clustering solutions fix both of these problems.

2) Yes. Altough technically speaking Terracotta only solves the shared memory part, not the CPU part. However by solving the memory part it automatically solves the CPU part since you can now just add JVM's to the shared memory space.

3) I don't know if thats practically possible but as a thought experiment; Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Clustering can mean one of the following:

1. Multiple instances can be managed as one.  Deploy an application to the cluster, it is deployed to all instances in the cluster.   Make a configuration change, and that change will be pushed to all nodes in the cluster.  GlassFish supports this out of the box.
2. Service Availability. If any one instance fails, the application is available on another instance.  Without high availability enabled, any instance failure also results in session loss for any session being managed by that instance. GlassFish supports this out of the box.
3. High availability. If any one instance fails, the application is available on another instance, *and* there is no session loss because a session replica is also maintained on another instance.  GlassFish supports this. You will have to choose either #2 or #3 in any one cluster.

What you are asking about IMHO is really #3, because it is the only real case where Terracotta - in the context of high availability clustering - will offer value w/GlassFish.  GlassFish already offers built-in high availability, so there had better be a very good reason to add Terracotta to the solution because it will complicate the deployment architecture.

The primary reason I can think of adding Terracotta is that you may want to offload session management to a data grid and free up GlassFish to run business logic. This may be due to more frequent garbage collection or wanting to manage more users per GlassFish instance. However, I'm not sure that Terracotta can do this seamlessly.  With GlassFish built-in HA clustering, replicating sessions is seamless (no application logic modifications).  You may have to write code to put/get data from a Terracotta cache I'll let you research :-)  Oracle GlassFish Server also integrates (seamlessly) with Coherence to solve this problem. You can separate session management into a Coherence data grid without modifying your application code.

Unless you know for a fact up front that your application must scale to a very large number of concurrent users, start with built-in HA clustering, run tests, and go from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With the point 2 please correct me if i am wrong but understand it refers to the fact that the deployment is across all of the instances so if an instance fails another one is called however this new does not know the session data the crashed one had, so  clustering is only used to have a way to continue not to preserve the session That is the difference in between point 3 High Availability YES do preserve the session., is it right?